# nginx with php7 or nginx with hhvm , Which one is good for API server

Tags: nginx, php-7, fastcgi, hhvm

I need some advice for choosing  my API Server.
1) NGINX + PHP7
2) NGINX + HHVM

Which one will  perform better ? 
Thanks in advance.